# php $_COOKIE only gets session cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies

`print_r($_COOKIE)` returns an array with only the session cookie and it's value, that is

```
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 0cfbom6llfl3ho93n7bljnns14 )
```

However, I did set other cookies. I checked the browser and they do exist. I did the setting like this:

```
setcookie("cookie_name",$myvar,
time() + (20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
"/", "mydomain.com",
true, true
);
```

The browser shows the cookie name as `cookie_name` and the value as the value of `$myvar` so apparently there's no problem in the setting of the cookie.

Looking at both cookies side-by-side on the browser the only difference is that the session cookie's domain is `mydomain.com` while `cookie_name`'s domain is `.mydomain.com`. Is that the problem? If so, how can I solve it?

Edit: The dot wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I set `seucre` to `true` and my webhost did not provide HTTPS so the cookie couldn't be accessed even server-side. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this page, Vist http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

The first note points out why it dose not work, only if when the browser send a request back(such as a normal page visit)

you can use Chrome inspector to check the browser's request's http head.

And i'm sorry for my poor English

Comment: Please elaborate. I can't get the $_COOKIE values I've set at any time. Not just after I set it, but neither after I refresh the page, nor after I close and then re-open my browser. All I get is the session cookie. Chorme inspector only shows the session cookie being requested, but I can see the cookies on chrome://cookies.